# How can I test google chromecast states with appium Ios java

Tags: json, appium, chromecast

I'm running automation tests on an app that has casting button from chromecast , is there anyway to access the chromecast states in order to validate information about it, if so, is there any possibility to do that with Ios-appium or maybe just in a java code? Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by chromecast states?

Comment: I want to know if it's connecting to Chromecast, buffering, casting. ready to cast, etc.